# Browser Back or Next Button Doesn't Work?

Tags: python, django, button, browser

I'm using django. When I press the "like button" the browser's back or next button doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

**views.py**

```
def like_post(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked = True
    return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
```

**detail.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if is_liked %}
          <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}" class="btn btn-danger">Beğenme</button>
        {% else %}
          <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Beğen</button>
        {% endif %}
      </form>
```

Comment: Are you **redirecting** the user in your view?

Comment: @PedramParsian I added views in issue. How can I do it?